# Populating datagrid columns using databinding

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I have a grid:

```
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Registration" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Registration}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

I have a list of registrations and types from:

```
Class MyListPage

Public Shared _item As New List(Of ItemType)()

Dim registrations As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
Dim types As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub

'Code in here to fill the two lists
End Class

Public Class ItemType
    Public _reg As String
    Public _type As String

    Public Property Registration() As String
    Get
        Return _reg
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _reg = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Type() As String
    Get
        Return _type
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _type = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

What I want to do, and have been trying to do, is bing the registrations and types to the two datagrid columns I have, and use an observable collection  (I think is what I want), to bind to them being updated dynamically.

But I am at an absolute loss where to go from here. registrations and types are both a list of about 10 elements, which obviously need to go into their respective columns. This is all new to me, so any help would be appreciated

I would quite like to be able to fill the columns one by one as the lists get populated.

Comment: You need to have a list of `ItemType` type instead of string and then bind the list to `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an `ObservableCollection(Of ItemType)` from a *public property* and bind to this one:

```
Class MyListPage

    Public Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of ItemType)()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        DataContext = Me
        'Populate the Items property here...
    End Sub
End Class
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```